# See song's license on Soundcloud

Tags: music, soundcloud

Is it possible to see what license an individual song has on Soundcloud? Some of the songs have Creative Commons but others appear to not have any license.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artists of songs without a CC license have opted for all rights to be reserved.

[image: All Rights Reserved]

So if you *do not see* something similar to the following (Creative Commons license icons below the genre):

[image: license appears under labels]

Then all rights are reserved.

Comment: I also notice that any track with a longish description will get a _"show more ▾"_ link. The CC license information may be hidden under that